# View not receiving touches after custom spinner is invoked

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I followed the guide here to make my own custom view pop up to indicate I am searching for the users results:
    http://joris.kluivers.nl/blog/2012/03/02/custom-popups-revisited/

When the search results are found, I dismiss the custom view, an a Flurry Ad pops up immediately. I click the x button on the ad and my next view appears. This view is not receiving any touch events anymore, neither is the tab bar at the bottom working. I suspect it has to do something with the custom view still animating away(via a transform to 0.0f) when the Flurry ad is coming up, but I am not sure. I am including the code for how the spinner is created, as well as the dismissal.

Note: I have confirmed the problem is related to Flurry Ads showing up modally while my customSpinner is going away. I don't know how to fix it though. When I don't display the Ad, the touch events are registering fine.

PCFFinder.c

```
- (void)queryServer:(NSString *)queryString  {
    __block PCFCustomSpinner *spinner = [[PCFCustomSpinner alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200):@"Searching.."];
    [spinner show];
    NSString *url = @"https://selfservice.mypurdue.purdue.edu/prod/bwckschd.p_get_crse_unsec";
    NSString *referer = @"https://selfservice.mypurdue.purdue.edu/prod/bwckgens.p_proc_term_date";
    dispatch_queue_t task = dispatch_queue_create("Task 3", nil);
    dispatch_async(task, ^{
        NSString *webData = [PCFWebModel queryServer:url connectionType:@"POST" referer:referer arguements:queryString];
        if (webData) {
            classesOffered = [PCFWebModel parseData:webData type:2];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [spinner dismiss];
                spinner = NULL;
                if ([classesOffered count] > 0) {
                    if (self.view.window)
                        searching = NO;
                        //the ad pops up in the next view controllers viewWillAppear method and after exiting the ad, the views no longer work
                        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ChooseClass" sender:self];
                }else {
                    [spinner dismiss];
                    PCFCustomAlertView *alert = [[PCFCustomAlertView alloc] initAlertView:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 200) :@"Search Results" :@"No results were found. Please try broadening the search or double check your input." :@"OK"];
                    [alert show];
                    //the views still work here though..
                    searching = NO;
                }
            });
//rest omitted because it is irrelevant.
}
```

CustomPopup.c

```
-(void)dismiss
{
    __block UIWindow *animatedWindow = self.window;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        animatedWindow.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.0f, 0.0f);
    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        animatedWindow.hidden = YES;
        animatedWindow = nil;
    }];
}

-(void)show
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    self.window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert;
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.window.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.window.bounds));
    [self.window addSubview:self];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    //animated
    self.window.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5f, 1.5f);
    self.window.alpha = 0.0f;

    __block UIWindow *animationWindow = self.window;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        animationWindow.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f);
        animationWindow.alpha = 1.0f;
    }completion:nil];

}
```

I have tried setting the view as first responder in the viewWillAppear method, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

In your dismiss method you are setting the single window to have a zero scale and hidden. This is surely your problem. Animate the pop ups view then remove it from the super view instead.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I added:
[animatedWindow removeFromSuperView]; before the nil statement. It still does not let me recieve touches. I don't understand why it works when I don't present the modal Ad, but it does when the Ad is not presented.

Comment: If you do oddball things, then it may be hard to figure out which oddball thing is the one that kills your app. Step back a few thousand meters (or feet) and just comment out some of this stuff. You should be able to find what works and what does not.

Comment: If I don't show my spinner, it works either way. I just don't know what effect showing my spinner has on the touch events. I am including the show method, hopefully that might help.

Comment: When I have odd things like this, I walk the current view up the chaing (ie view, view.superview, ...) and look at a bunch of properties. Like who accepts user interaction. who is first responder, etc. This is detective work - there is no simple solution. When you finally find the answer it will be understandable, its just something unexplained right now. I have no magic solution to offer.